# Not able to get auto generated Id, using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have two Entities. One is UserEntity and other is TaskEntity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    private String userEmail;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_email")
    private List<TaskEntity> tasks;

    //getter setter for variables
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="task")
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String statusDate;
    private String status;

    //getter setter for variables
}
```

Now I want to create a new task based on userEmail, so this I am doing as follow in DAO class:

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    public Integer addNewTaskByUserEmail(Task task, String userEmail) {
        UserEntity userEntity = em.find(UserEntity.class, userEmail);
        TaskEntity taskEntity = new TaskEntity();
        taskEntity.setName(task.getName());
        taskEntity.setDescription(task.getDescription());
        taskEntity.setStatus(task.getStatus());
        taskEntity.setStatusDate(task.getDate());
        userEntity.getTasks().add(taskEntity);
        return taskEntity.getId();
    }
```

But in the return statement of I am getting null in service class. How can I return the auto-generated taskId?

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is you are not saving a task associated with the user. Save the task and then you might be able to get the taskId.

```
public Integer addNewTaskByUserEmail(Task task, String userEmail) {
    UserEntity userEntity = em.find(UserEntity.class, userEmail);
    TaskEntity taskEntity = new TaskEntity();
    taskEntity.setName(task.getName());
    taskEntity.setDescription(task.getDescription());
    taskEntity.setStatus(task.getStatus());
    taskEntity.setStatusDate(task.getDate());
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(taskEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    userEntity.getTasks().add(taskEntity);
    return taskEntity.getId();
}
```

OR

```
    @Autowired TaskRepository taskRepository

    public Integer addNewTaskByUserEmail(Task task, String userEmail) {
        UserEntity userEntity = em.find(UserEntity.class, userEmail);
        TaskEntity taskEntity = new TaskEntity();
        taskEntity.setName(task.getName());
        taskEntity.setDescription(task.getDescription());
        taskEntity.setStatus(task.getStatus());
        taskEntity.setStatusDate(task.getDate());
        taskEntity = taskRepository.save(taskEntity)
        userEntity.getTasks().add(taskEntity);
        return taskEntity.getId();
    }
```

Where `TaskRepository` will be

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskEntity, Integer>  
{  

}
```

Comment: I am getting error in the first method which you suggest, and I am not getting what is this TaskRepository. can you please give explain little, I am new to JPA.

Comment: I have added the `TaskRepository` which provides the basic methods to perform certain actions such as *save, findById, findAll* etc.

Comment: For the first method, please update the question with detailed stack trace

Comment: Hello @Ashsih, Have you added these?

Comment: Nope, I don't have an idea about JpaRepository.